# I invoke @Composable from the context of a @Composable function but still recieve an error

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Basically the main issue is in the header, here is my code snippet:

```
@Composable
fun CustomRadioGroupItemComponent(
    radioOptions: List<String>,
    onSelectBehavior: (optionIndex: Int, onOptionSelected: (Int) -> Unit) -> Unit,
    imageStateCheck: (selectedOption: Int) -> Boolean
): Int {

    if (radioOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
        val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember {
            mutableStateOf(0)
        }

        RadioGroup {

            radioOptions.forEachIndexed { index, item ->

                RadioGroupItem(
                    selected = false,
                    onSelect = {
                        onSelectBehavior(index, onOptionSelected)
                    }
                ) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                        if (imageStateCheck(selectedOption)) {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(
                                    id =
                                    R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked
                                ), contentDescription = null
                            )
                        } else {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(
                                    id =
                                    R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked
                                ), contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                        ClickableText(
                            text = AnnotatedString(item),
                            style = TextStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.nunito_light))),
                            onClick = {
                                onSelectBehavior(index, onOptionSelected)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return selectedOption
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I recieve this error near `Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {` line, which located right under the RadioGroupItem and for each loop:

`@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Is there any workaround? I stuck on this heavily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioGroup` and `RadioGroupItem` were [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#0.1.0-dev15) and [removed](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#0.1.0-dev17) over a year ago:

> Previously deprecated RadioGroup and RadioGroupItems have been removed. Use Row and RadioBotton instead

Don't use tutorials older than February 24, 2021 (that's the day compose went into beta and stabilized the API), because they likely contain obsolete code.

Make sure you're using latest stable version of Compose. Right now it's 1.0.1.

I suggest you study modern [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation) and [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial)

Comment: Actually Studio does not support 1.0.1 yet Philip. I mean it can run, but we need to do some manually dependency modifications for the Kotlin Version in the gradle settings file. The default template still configures the project for 1.0.0 as of Canary 10. Projects won't compile if we simply change the version in the project level build.

Comment: @MARSK there's Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1, it is most recent stable version of AS, and it supports 1.0.1

Comment: @PhilipDukhov thank you! Is there any comprehensive docs for compose? I am struggling with finding one

Comment: But the Canary still uses 1.0.0. Doesn't make sense. Are you getting confused with 'suuport'? It can run, but we need to do some modifications in settings.gradle.

Comment: @MARSK not sure what's the problem in your case, with Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Canary 10 I can use 1.1.0-alpha02. Check out on your gradle plugin, or IDK

Comment: @FUJI I've added links to docs and tutorials to my answer